# Highlighting bands of a matrix with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, highlighting, nicematrix

I am trying to highlight specific band diagonals of a matrix in latex using `nicematrix` and `tikz`, but I am having trouble with fitting the bands to the matrix correctly.

Does someone have an idea of what I am doing wrong here ? See the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{bNiceArray}{ccccccc}[columns-width=auto]
d_{1}&e_{u,1}&\cdots&&&&0\\
c_{l,2}&d_{2}&e_{u,2}&\cdots&&&\vdots\\
b_{l,3}&c_{l3}&d_{3}&e_{u,3}&\cdots&&\vdots\\
a_{l,4}&b_{l,4}&c_{l,4}&d_{4}&e_{u,4}&\cdots&\vdots\\
0&&&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
\vdots&&a_{l,n-1}&b_{l,n-1}&c_{l,n-1}&d_{n-1}&e_{u,n-1}\\
\vdots&\cdots&&a_{l,n}&b_{l,n}&c_{l,n}&d_{n}\\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw=red, rounded corners=2pt, inner ysep = 1pt,
       rotate fit=-35, fit = (1-1) (7-7) ] {} ;
\node [trapezium, trapezium angle=55, draw=blue, inner ysep = 0pt, rounded corners=2pt,rotate fit=-35,fit= (1-2) (6-7) ]{};
\node [trapezium, trapezium angle=55, draw=green, inner xsep = 0pt,inner ysep = 0pt, rounded corners=2pt,rotate fit=-215,fit= (2-1)(4-1)(7-6)(7-4) ]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

and end up with an equation looking like this:

[image: band matrix output]

Ideally, I would like to have the green and blue trapezoids neatly fit into the matrix itself and not overflow.

I think it would help if the column and row widths of the matrix were also the same, but I do not know how I can set that.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing?

Comment: I have now updated the code to be compilable

Comment: Does it have to be a trapezium node and the `fit` library? On that note, you're only adding the most upper-left and most lower-right nodes to the `fit` key instead of all of them inbetween?

Comment: No, it definitely does not have be a trapezium node, or with the `fit` library. I am happy with any shape and library. Adding the lower left node did not help either. I have updated the code with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suggestion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{bNiceArray}{ccccccc}[columns-width=auto,extra-margin=6pt]
d_{1}&e_{u,1}&\cdots&&&&0\\
c_{l,2}&d_{2}&e_{u,2}&\cdots&&&\vdots\\
b_{l,3}&c_{l3}&d_{3}&e_{u,3}&\cdots&&\vdots\\
a_{l,4}&b_{l,4}&c_{l,4}&d_{4}&e_{u,4}&\cdots&\vdots\\
0&&&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
\vdots&&a_{l,n-1}&b_{l,n-1}&c_{l,n-1}&d_{n-1}&e_{u,n-1}\\
\vdots&\cdots&&a_{l,n}&b_{l,n}&c_{l,n}&d_{n}\\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
  \draw [red] ([yshift=-2mm]1-|1.5) -- ([yshift=-2mm]7.5-|8) |- (8-|7.5) -- (1.5-|1) |- cycle ; 
  \draw [blue] ([yshift=-1mm]1-|1.5) -- ([yshift=-1mm]7.5-|8) -- (6.5-|8) -- ([yshift=-1mm]1-|2.5) -- cycle ;
  \draw [green] ([yshift=-1mm]1.5-|1) -- ([yshift=-1mm]8-|7.5) -- ([yshift=-1mm]8-|4.5) -- (4.5-|1) -- cycle ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]